# Unable to successfully import Visual Python in Python 3.4.3

Tags: numpy, python-3.4, vpython

Upon trying to import VPython as follows on IDLE -

```
from visual import *
```

I get the following error message -

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        from visual import *
    File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\visual\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .visual_all import *
    File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\visual\visual_all.py", line 1, in <module>
        from vis import version
    File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\vis\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from .cvisual import (vector, dot, mag, mag2, norm, cross, rotate,
SystemError: initialization of cvisual raised unreported exception
```

What could be the reason? How can I resolve this issue?

I was careful to install all dependencies along with the VPython package namely, TTFQuery, Fonttools and Polygon. All of the packages, by which I mean even numpy, where installed from binaries (wheel files) as available on Christoph Gohlke's site

Comment: Instead of import visual, can you add the result from `import numpy.core.multiarray`? That seems to be the core of your problem, but the website you mention, does provide numpy 1.9.2., for which that should work.

Comment: Going back I realized I had installed an unoptimized version of numpy and installing the right binary worked though I still ended up getting an unrelated error of syntax in ttfquery! Thanks for the help though!